# MYSQL JOIN same table, merge empty fields and sum

Tags: mysql, join

I have two rows which belongs to the same purchase order.
As you can see below the commission and sales_value are not combine in to one row. This data we receive externally and no possibility to change.

I'm already trying for around a week to get the correct query, unfortunately not with the results which I expected

```
+--------+-------------+------------+-------+
|   PO   | sales_value | commission | total |
+--------+-------------+------------+-------+
| XXXXXX |             |      -1.60 | -1.60 |
| XXXXXX |       28.89 |            | 28.89 |
+--------+-------------+------------+-------+
```

I try to create a query to get the following result:

```
+--------+-------------+------------+-------+
|   PO   | sales_value | commission | total |
+--------+-------------+------------+-------+
| XXXXXX |       28.89 |      -1.60 | 27.29 |
+--------+-------------+------------+-------+
```

It should move commission to the empty commission field in second row & it should sum total amounts together. In this way we could use the information properly.

I tried many possibilities together with the join function of MySQL.
unfortunately I cannot show my try outs because I didn't save the test queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP BY` with [`SUM()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) aggregation, in order to club all the rows for a particular PO into one:

```
SELECT
  PO,
  SUM(sales_value) AS sales_value, 
  SUM(commission) AS commission, 
  SUM(sales_value) + SUM(commission) AS total
FROM your_table_name -- <- use your table name here
GROUP BY PO
```

Comment: This looks so simple tho.. Learned a new point of view, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select po,
sum(ifnull(sales_value,0)) as sales_value,
sum(ifnull(commission,0)) as commission,
sum(ifnull(total,0)) as total
 from
#yourtable
group by po
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.